# Top Nav submenus wpon't stay open - only in FF and only sometimes

Tags: navigation, headers, sub-menu

I've been up and down my header and nav trying to find why the top nav submenus won't stay open about 50% of the time. This doesn't happen in any other browser, but it's a significant enough issue in just FF that I have to get it fixed.

the url is http://www.cmslaser.com. The issue is not page-dependent, either.

Comment: This is unfortunately way too localized. Something like this is really hard to debug as this is not a consistent problem. I would suggest to turn debug on and look for obvious errors and problems. This might also be due to some cache, but again, there is no way to pin point this. If debug shows no errors, you are going to have a tough time tracking this. Also, look at your server logs and see if you can pick up something there. Good luck with this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be good old-fashioned css-problem:
The top level li is 93 px high (by the link in it: 38px padding top, 16px line-height, 39px padding-bottom), the sub-navigation starts at top: 96px.

Now for the backgrounds of your problem:
The subnavigation is shown while your mouse hovers over the li (or something within the li). While you move your mouse from the top-level-li to the subnavigation-ul, your mousepointer moves over 3 px "free" space, which is not in the li. Sometimes you are fast enough so that the subnav is not invisible yet when you get to the ul (which is within the li so that the li is in hoverstate again), other times, you are not this fast, which makes the subnav disappear.

How to fix this: make the toplevel navigation links higher or move the subnav higher.

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on...my css had the subnav starting at 92.  i changed it to 88 and the problem is solved...at least tested this far. i'd not have looked at moving it up as they had a 1px overlap according to my code.  thanks!